# PLSQL aggregation function using type object PARALLEL_ENABLE AGGREGATE

Tags: oracle, plsql, sql-function, sql-types

I have question. Already i have avg_new function, which include nulls (as 0) in  the result. I have start from [linkedin](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/generate-aggregate-functions-plsql-arash-atarzadeh/) link.
Code:

```
select avg(a),avg_new(nvl(a,-9999)) from
(select 'test' h, 2 a from dual
union all
select 'test' h, null a from dual
union all
select 'test' h, 2 a from dual
union all
select 'test' h ,2 a from dual)
```

the results are
`2; 1,5`

I would like to extend avg_new function by adding denominator parameter ex.:

```
avg_new(nvl(a,-9999),10)
```

Te result should be then 0.6

Default value of the parameter would be null, then function works as previous example. If the parameter would be >0 then I would divide sum of 'a' by value of this parameter. How i could do this? I would like to pass this parameter to used type object and to perform further calculations there. Is it possible?

```
create or replace FUNCTION avg_new (input NUMBER , denominator NUMBER DEFAULT NULL) RETURN NUMBER 
PARALLEL_ENABLE AGGREGATE USING T_avg_new;
```

Right now the type could proper read only the first parameter. After adding i have errors:

ORA-29925: cannot execute T_avg_new.ODCIAGGREGATEINITIALIZE

ORA-06553: PLS-306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to "ODCIAGGREGATEINITIALIZE"

29925. 00000 -  "cannot execute %s"

*Cause:    The specified function does not exist or does not have an
appropriate signature.

*Action:   Implement the function with the appropriate signature.

Comment: Just to clarify, how is the `parallel_enable` setting related to the issue?

Comment: Regarding your compilation error, it would be helpful to see the whole implementation for avg_new and t_avg_new, so we can see how you are calling ODCIAGGREGATEINITIALIZE.